# How to retrieve JsonObject data on MVC

Tags: android, model-view-controller, json

I have an android app which send jsonobject to server as follow:

```
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("snc", serialClient);
        jsonParam.put("code", hashString(pwd + serialClient));

        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        String str = jsonParam.toString();
        byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        printout.write(data);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close ();
```

And the MVC Controller as follow:

```
<System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("Post")> _
Public Function Android_Index(ByVal data As String) As ActionResult
    Dim param As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(data)

    For Each p In param
        LogEntry(p.Key & vbCrLf & p.Value, 0, "test")
    Next

    Return RedirectToLocal("/UI/Forbidden")
End Function
```

But I receive the data as empty-no element object. Please help to find where I am going wrong and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I have tried to create a MVC class as follow:

```
Public Class SNC
    Public snc As String
    Public code As String
End Class
```

And edit the controller as follow:

```
Public Function Android_Index(ByVal data As SNC) As ActionResult
    LogEntry(data.snc, 0, "test")
    LogEntry(data.code, 0, "test")

    ......
End Function
```

When the android app tried to send the jsonobject, I can confirm the Android_Index has been hit. So I assume the jsonobject should accepted in the "data" parameter. But both "snc" and "code" are blank string. While I have re-check from the android that both "snc" and "code" which sent as jsonobject is not empty. For now, it seems the problem is in android side. Or the way how mvc should accept is not in correct way?

Comment: your issue is from server side or android side?

Comment: @dipali please see the update. I still tried to follow where is the issue coming from.

Comment: please print string "str" in log.and check its create a proper json or not?if your issue is server side code then i can't help you.but if your issue is creating json,then definately i will help you.

Comment: @dipali, the string str value is {"snc":"6MYGLSZR9G1PJCUE","code":"Rqo0bfN7Hdlt5vR4rn4S9ERHw\/4="}

Comment: your Json is valid.so your issue is for server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours with nothing, finally I can make it work.

The issue is on java side:

First I have to assign the jsonobject to a key as follow:

```
JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("snc", serialClient);
jsonParam.put("code", hashString(pwd + serialClient));
String param = "data=" + jsonParam.toString(); //assign jsonParam to identifier
```

Then set the Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
The post data finally catched correctly by the Controller.